# How to parse timestamp either as NTP timestamp or units?

Tags: c#, .net, parsing, datetime, time

I need to parse a timestamp value than can either be given as NTP time or as short time string with unit characters.

Examples:

```
time = 604800 (can cast to long, easy!)
```

or

```
time = 7d
```

Is there a built-in date time parsing functionality in .NET for such cases? Or do I have to look for any character that is not numeric (probably with regex?).

The following characters are expected to occur:

```
  d - days 
  h - hours 
  m - minutes 
  s - seconds
```

Comment: There is no built-in .NET method to achieve this very specifi formating. You can do it with Regex.

Comment: @CédricBignon Well, how? I'm not very familiar with regex patterns and it looks like rocket science for me to 'quickly' write a parsing pattern.

Comment: First you have to be extremely clear how you expect the formated string to be. Is `"7d 5s 8h"` valid? Is `"7 d 5 h"` valid? Is `"7d8h"` valid?

Comment: @CédricBignon According to the specification I have, only 1 time entity is valid. If the NTP value would be `604801` (which is basically `7d 1s`), the data should be represented by the next possible smaller unit, so the only possible value in this case would be `604801s`. Format is only valid like in the example above. (`<int><unit>` without spaces and such). Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: In that case, a using Regex is may be to much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No Regex is needed for such a basic operation.

```
public static int Process(string input)
{
    input = input.Trim();                                          // Removes all leading and trailing white-space characters 

    char lastChar = input[input.Length - 1];                       // Gets the last character of the input

    if (char.IsDigit(lastChar))                                    // If the last character is a digit
        return int.Parse(input, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);     // Returns the converted input, using an independent culture (easy ;)

    int number = int.Parse(input.Substring(0, input.Length - 1),   // Gets the number represented by the input (except the last character)
                           CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);          // Using an independent culture

    switch (lastChar)
    {
        case 's':
            return number;
        case 'm':
            return number * 60;
        case 'h':
            return number * 60 * 60;
        case 'd':
            return number * 24 * 60 * 60;
        default:
            throw new ArgumentException("Invalid argument format.");
    }
}
```

Comment: `(easy ;)` <- don't do this. It looks horrible. :) Yes, I see I was heading for way to much, although it's for a protocol and I will be never sure what weird stuff a client could send me. So I guess I should add further format validation checks. Thank you very much for your solution, it does exactly what I intended.